# Facing classes full debug.jar missing when generating build for framework android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, android-source

I am creating a framework build by downloading from aosp where I am migrating to 9.0 but when I run the command after env.set up by giving mm,

It displays error as,Local SDK version missing.

When I given LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current in mk file, it runs and throws error as

```
   'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/CmdWrapper_intermediates/classes-header.jar', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/MonitorService_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Comment: . build/envSetup.sh && make framework

Comment: Thanks. Let me check.

Comment: dont forget to call lunch with appropriate config before make

Comment: I used this but I am  getting error as  Error = libjni_jpegstream (native:ndk:libc++:static) should not link to libjpeg (native:platform)